# Is there an equivalent of qbChatDialog.getCustomData on the Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, quickblox, quickblox-android

I've been trying to se the quicklox javascript chat API but when I try to retrieve the custom data that is joined to the chat dialog I cannot find a method for it.

I have tried querying it separately as follows:

```
var className = "CustomDialogItem";
            var data = {_parent_id  :dialog._id};
            // use filter or ids to get records:
            QB.data.list(className, data, function (error, result) {
              if (error) {
                console.log(error);
              } else {
                console.log("result"+result);
              }
            });
```

Strill doesn't retrieve any result. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is Nikolay from QuickBlox support.

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent method for our Javascript SDK.

Please follow our documentation:
https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/js-chat-dialogs#create-dialog-with-custom-parameters
https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/js-chat-dialogs#retrieve-dialogs-by-custom-parameters

Comment: I appreciate the response. Had to find other creative ways to go about it